# Symfony Validation on Relations

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

Suppose I have the following Entities:
Pizza
PizzaType = [Cheese, Meat, Vegetable, Supreme]
Toppings = [Pepperoni, Sausage, Peppers, Mushrooms]

When I create a pizza and set its type to Meat I want to be able to validate that only a "meat" type of topping is chosen, same with Vegetable, while supreme will allow any topping (meat or vegetable)... Assume there is already a property for each topping that maps to a pizza type. Really just interested in know what type of validator to use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a callback to `validation_groups` option in your form for the desired field. Callback will have access to submitted data like this

```
... 'validation_groups' => static function (FormInterface $form) {

$data = $form->getData();

// your logic to determine validation groups

}
```

in there you can check what has been submitted and return an array of validation groups, different for each type of entity you want.

You can find more info here
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html

Comment: thanks... I'll mark as answer but I didnt actually even need to go as far as a validation group.. The answer ended up being a "Callback". I created a function in my entity, decorated it with #[Assert\Callback] ... initially it didn't work and I wasnt getting any errors but it was because I forgot the use statement for use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;